# Counting factors in a list?

Tags: python, list, count

Okay so I made a list called numbersList, a variable number = 20, count = 0, and spot = 0.

```
numbersList = range(1, 11)
number = 20
count = 0
spot = 0.
```

I want to count the numbers in the list that go into 20. I tried this:

```
while spot <= len(numbersList):
    if(number % int(numbersList[spot]) == 0):
        count = count + 1
    spot = spot + 1
print count
```

But it keeps saying list index is out of range. Please help!

Comment: The `when` keyword is new to me.

Comment: i meant while. my apologies. @Hyperboreus

Answer (score 2):

Your index goes too far at the last iteration of the `while` loop. Change the `<=` to `<` and it should work:

```
while spot < len(numbersList):
```

Or just use a `for` loop:

```
for i in numbersList:
    if number % i == 0:
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't index into a list with a float, and spot = 0. is a float.  Try removing that spurious period!

Comment: This gives a `TypeError` rather than an `IndexError`, which is what the questioner has.

Comment: Nice observations, but I don't think this is the only problem.  This gives me a TypeError and not an IndexError.  At least for python 3.3.

Comment: Yeah, I think that was an error introduced by posting the question.  The real error was pointed out above by Blender, and it's a fencepost error :)

Answer (score 1):

The first line is a SyntaxError

```
>>> when spot <= len(numbersList):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    when spot <= len(numbersList):
```

I suspect you mean to use `while`

But it's easier to use a for loop

```
for spot in numbersList:
    if number % spot == 0:
        count += 1
print count
```

This can also be written more simply by passing a generator expression to sum

```
count = sum(number % spot == 0 for spot in numbersList)
```

Comment: I really like Python for the succinct code like your revised generator expression. Nice example!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the classic *map-reduce*

```
 reduce( lambda x,y: x+y, [ number%spot for spot in numbersList ] )
```

Comment: As I see it, it computes the sum of the remainders, which is different from the count requested; possibly this can be salvaged by replacing "number%spot" by "int(number % spot == 0)"